# Use different Country/Region from Family in App Store

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore, internationalization

My family is from Brazil and I live in Romania. I use family sharing so I can use Apple Music from my family account without paying for an extra individual subscription. This is the main feature I am interested in. However, I need to use Romanian apps and I cannot find them in the App Store because my Country/Region is set to Brazil, and not Romania. I cannot change it in the settings because it says:

> The country/region for your Family is managed by

Is it possible to use another Country/Region so I can purchase Romanian apps while still using my family's Apple Music subscription?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. All Family Sharing members have to be in the same Country/Region.

As stated in this Support article:

> Not all content and content types are available in all countries or regions. To share purchased content, all family members must use the same Apple ID country or region.

- https://support.apple.com/HT201085

Comment: I don't want to share purchased content though. The interface [makes it look](https://i.imgur.com/gOo0s7E.jpg) like I can deactivate this feature, but in practice it won't let me. Is it possible to deactivate purchase sharing only for me?

Comment: What if all I want to share is the 2TB of iCloud storage only? Has nothing to do with location...

Comment: It's fairly disgusting that this point is in grey coloured hard to read "fine print" at the bottom of the page - it's very ugly and beneath Apple to do that. I bought the subscription to share iCloud 2TB with my family and now I'm left sorely disappointed with a charge on my Credit Card to boot.

Answer (score 2):

Your Apple ID is only valid for one country. You can create another free Apple ID with a Romanian billing address (and you will most probably need a Romanian payment method, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202631). You can have multiple Apple IDs. The billing address associated with it determines with store you can use with it.